# What is this notation doing? CSS content: "\e850";

Tags: css

I'm looking at the CSS file of my Wordpress theme. But these lines are new for me:

```
ul.flex-direction-nav li a.flex-next:before{content: "\e850";} 
ul.flex-direction-nav li a.flex-prev:before {content: "\e84f";}
```

What is this content: "\e850"; attribute for? I've never seen such thing before.

Comment: Is this a foreign character by any chance? Displays as a box for me within jsfiddle. Edit: yes it's an invalid unicode character so it must be.

Comment: [12.1 The :before and :after pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content)

Comment: @JoelMurphy: not exactly, give a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two lines of CSS add characters before elements: http://jsfiddle.net/Mm58r/

`\e850` ([here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e850/index.htm)) and `\e84f` ([here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e84f/index.htm)) are code for theses characters. I personnaly don't see them on my computer, but they exists in certain fonts ;)

More information:

- [The :before and :after pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content)
- [Index of Unicode characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a.htm)

Comment: They're Chinese characters. This is what I see (If it comes through for you) ""

Answer (score 2):

The CSS property `content` is used only with pseudo element selectors (like `:before` or `:after`), and defines their content, that is something added at the begin or at the end of the element they refer to.

`\e850` is a [CSS escape code](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#escaped-characters): it represents the Unicode character U+E850, which is a character in the private user area. The other one (U+E84F) comes from that area too.

Such characters are often used in CSS combined with special font to insert *font icons*
, which are monochromatic icons. The characters are taken from the private user area because they are not meant to be read for example by screen readers.